# The sx styling for Drawer element does not work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an elementary component.
With sx I try to add styles, but they are not added to the Drawer, but to its parent block and because of this the styles are not applied.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";

export const Menu= () => {
  return (
    <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      sx={{ width: 240, fontSize: 14, bgcolor: "green" }}
    >
      <Typography>My Own Logo</Typography>
    </Drawer>
  );
};
```

[Blocks with styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Tna.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to step into the root css of the drawer:

```
<Drawer
  variant="permanent"
  sx={{ "& .MuiDrawer-paper": { width: 240, backgroundColor: "green" } }}
>
  <Typography fontSize={22}>My Own Logo</Typography>
</Drawer>
```

Control the font size with the Typography component.

[Here's a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-tu-7qdn1?file=/src/App.js:289-339)

Comment: Thank you Rolando! It helps!

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure to mark my answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mui v5, you can also define the sx prop on the Drawer's PaperProps, like this:

```
export const Menu= () => {
  return (
    <Drawer
      variant="permanent"
      PaperProps={{
        sx: {
          width: 240,
          fontSize: 14,
          background-color: green,
        }
      }}
    >
      <Typography>My Own Logo</Typography>
    </Drawer>
  );
};
```